# This is not calling the servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have this code

```
<form method="post" action="localhost:8080/WelcomeServlet">
  <select name="Signal_Drop">
    <option value="True">True</opion>
  </select>
  <select name="Video_Glitch">
    <option value="True">True</option>
  </select>
  <select name="Call_Drop">
    <option value="True">True</option>
  </select>
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I click the submit button, the page is not changing. Nothing happens. It is not calling the servlet.

Answer (score 3):

Write

```
http://localhost:8080/WelcomeServlet
```

instead of just

```
localhost:8080/WelcomeServlet
```

And you perhaps have to add the context of your WAR before the Servlet name.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use:

```
<form method="post" action="/WelcomeServlet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
localhost:8080/WelcomeServlet
```

write

```
/WelcomeServlet
```

It's not very good to write absolute address here.

Answer (score 0):

first you've a small html bug at line 3 `</opion>` instead of `</option>`

second , I agree with the two first answers avoid absolute urls as the server will resolve the url automagicaly.

web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.lab.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WelcomeServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

your form

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="WelcomeServlet">
    <select name="Signal_Drop">
        <option value="True">
            True
            </option>
    </select> <select name="Video_Glitch">
        <option value="True">True</option>
    </select> <select name="Call_Drop">
        <option value="True">True</option>
    </select> <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Hope it'll help you